# Why can't MAMP start apache server?

Tags: apache, windows-10, mamp

When I start MAMP, apache turns green for a second, turns back off then the MySQL server starts. MAMP was the first server I've tried to download on this pc. I had it on another PC a few months ago, and I had no problems.

I've checked the ports, but nothing else is running on 80. I also tried changing the port to 9999, 8000, 8080, and 8888.

I saw that
    LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
in MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf can cause this problem in windows 10, but commenting it out didn't fix it.

I also saw that it could be caused by "distro breaking up ssl directives"
I don't know much about ssl or virtual hosts so I'm reluctant to make changes to something controlling security. Plus it doesn't give the name of the file. It also says to check the server status, but the server isn't running, so I can't.

This is the error log

```
[Fri Oct 04 11:44:24 2019] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri Oct 04 11:44:25 2019] [warn] pid file C:/MAMP/bin/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Oct 04 11:44:25 2019] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Oct 04 11:44:25 2019] [notice] Digest: done
```